# ViewPager changed position checkBox event again active

Tags: android

I have very simple question . I used View Pager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter in my app.

***View Pager Tabs position respectively  : Game|Movie|Study***

I used checkbox in StudyFragment. First , I checked checkbox in Study Tab and changed tab position(for example Game Tab ). Then I re-click Study Tab check box's  OnCheckedListener event was active and toast message again appeared. My PagerAdapter code shown as below :

```
public class PagerAdapter  extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment frag=null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                frag=new GameFragment();
                Log.i("PagerAdapter","pos0");
                break;
            case 1:
                frag=new MovieFragment();
                Log.i("PagerAdapter","pos1");

                break;
            case 2:
                frag=new StudyFragment();
                Log.i("PagerAdapter","pos2");

                break;
        }
        return frag;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title=" ";
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                title="Game";
                break;
            case 1:
                title="Movie";
                break;
            case 2:
                title="Study";
                break;
        }

        return title;
    }
}
```

Study Fragment code as below  :

```
public class StudyFragment extends Fragment {

CheckBox checkBox;
    public StudyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_study, container, false);
        checkBox=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "not checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }


}
```

I don't want that toast message again shown when changed tab. So I don't want triggered checkBox isChecked decision when re-changed tab How to fix it ?

*I fixed problem for me. When I changed tab I destroy previously fragment. 
add this line ViewPagerAdapter*

```
@Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
            trans.remove((Fragment) object);
            trans.commit();

    }
```

Comment: I would recommend to implement a `OnPageChangeListener` for your `ViewPager`, set a `flag` and pass it to our `Fragment` via `Interface`, and check in `onCheckedChanged` for the `flag`. For this simple task this seems to be a overkill - but maybe there is more you want to control... :)

Comment: It should be a simpler solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)   {
        //do stuff
    if(isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "not checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Also give pageoffsetlimit to your ViewPager Object:

```
viewPagerObj.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

If it doesn't work just let me know i will help you to solve it out and will find another solutions :)

Answer (score -1):

"FragmentStatePagerAdapter is used is to populate a large number of fragments in ViewPager, it destroys the fragment when it is not visible to the user and only savedInstanceState bundle of the fragment is kept in memory. When a page is revisited the adapter creates a new instance."

That's the reason why you're seeing toast again.

Try using FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePager, I think it should solve the issue.

[check out this post for more details](https://prashantsolanki3.github.io/blog/android/FRAGMENTPAGERADAPTER-VS-FRAGMENTSTATEPAGERADAPTER/)

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." - [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hey @Amy , I have edited the answer.  Is it correct now?

Answer (score -1):

Just update you fragment with one override method:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    checkBox.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: OnStart work after onCreateView method.  So this is incorrect solution.

Comment: I assume the poster would like to keep the `checked` state and simply does not want the `Toast` to appear..

Comment: Is there any idea for this solution ? @Amy

Comment: What you exactly looking for please describe..?

Comment: I don't want  triggered checkBox isChecked decision when re-changed tab

Comment: ok i got that..
You want when you  come back to that tab/fragment you want tht checkbox shud be unchecked.?
ok for that pls add this in your Fragment:

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }

Comment: Yes exactly. But checkbox still checked.

Comment: How to reset fragmentpageradapter memory ?

Comment: is that helps you ?
@How to reset fragmentpageradapter memory ? i cant get it what you want reset ?
Is that you want you page should be on 1st tab on some click event?